# Ember.js: How to pass parameters from one component to another component?

Tags: ember.js

I have "column-preview" component which contains list of columns with checkbox. I have another component "grid" which contains data table. Now depending upon checks in "column-preview" component I want hide/show columns. I have hidden column array in "column-preview' component which I want to pass it to the "grid" component. How to pass it from one component to another component ?

Answer (score 0):

- Declare selected column array property in controller to the specific route and pass it down to both `column-preview` component and `grid` component.
- Introduce parentComponent and declare selected column array property in parentComponent and pass it down to both `column-preview` component and `grid` component.
- Introduce `service` to share state between `column-preview` component and `grid` component.

The above practices might be helpful to follow [DDAU](https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/10/14/best-practices-data-down-actions-up)(DataDown ActionsUp) principle.